# Energy/cost for magnetic lasso

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, gimp

The GIMP's implementation for magnetic lasso ([found here](https://github.com/GNOME/gimp/blob/b3d2324527d9b805fa88dd2c8184030eaf4ac4bf/app/tools/gimpiscissorstool.c) in function **calculate_link()**) seems to be only using the **image gradient magnitude and direction** but not the **laplacian zero-crossing** as in the original paper *[Intelligent Scissors for Image Composition](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse455/02wi/readings/mort-sigg95.pdf)* by Mortensen and Barrett. The results seem to be good though. Do you confirm?

Comment: Check this, it works not bad : https://github.com/slash-segmentation/livewire

Comment: You're asking for an opinion, this is out of scope for SO. This is a Q&A site, not a chat site. You could instead ask, for example, for the technical differences between the two methods.

Comment: Zero crossings of the 2nd derivative are more difficult to use than local maxima of the 1st derivative. This is, for example, also why the Canny edge detector has become so popular. Also, it's possible to extend gradients to enlarge the caption zone, see for example [gradient vector flow](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/661186/).

Comment: @Andrey: very relevant ideed!

Comment: @Chris: haha! This is very interesting. Do you mean 2nd derivatives are difficult to use because they are more sensitive to noise?

Comment: If you find that the intelligent scissors in GIMP can be improved, please do not hesitate to provide a patch.